# blank image in firefox version 50

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am displaying blank image with:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs="
```

In all the browsers and in Firefox (until version 50) the blank image use to show the background color which is black.

I've update my FF version to 50 and now I see white color square instead of my black background color.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the metadata of your file (which is a GIF and not a jpeg by the way), we can see that the flag `Has Alpha` is not set.

Latest Firefox might have updated their gif parser and are probably now expecting this flag.

Anyway, here is an other 1x1px transparent gif that will work in all browsers: `"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAAL‌​AAAAAABAAEAQAICRAEAO‌​w=="`

```css
body{
   background-color: ivory;
  }
div{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAQAICRAEAOw==);
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: has the GIF format been upgraded to support alpha channel, or it's just the internal name of good old transparent colour feature?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I have to admit I don't know... That's what my *get Info* told me as differences between OP's and my version, but I can't really find this flag in specs.